# Loading third party library with Angular-cli

Tags: angular

This is related to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38855891/angular-cli-webpack-how-to-add-or-bundle-external-js-files) and this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334505/how-to-load-obj-model-with-three-js-in-typescript) but neither of those fit my needs.

I'm migrating an Angular2 app over to the `angular-cli` structure and I'm trying to include the `.OBJLoader` & `.MTLLoader` for the `threejs` library in my migrated project.

I've included the scripts from the `threejs` node folder in my `.angular-cli.json` file like this:

```
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/three/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js",
        "../node_modules/three/examples/js/loaders/MTLLoader.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
```

Because the `.OBJLoader` & `.MTLLoader` don't have typings I thought that I'd have to create them myself in the `typings.d.ts` file:

```
/* SystemJS module definition */
declare var module: NodeModule;
interface NodeModule {
  id: string;
}

// OBJLoader
declare var objloader: OBJLoader;
interface OBJLoader {

}

// MTLLoader
declare var mtlloader: MTLLoader;
interface MTLLoader {

}
```

I then tried to import the modules into the service I required them in like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import * as THREE from 'three';
import * as OBJLoader from 'OBJLoader';
import * as MTLLoader from 'MTLLoader';

@Injectable()
export class LoaderService {

    constructor() {}

    setupMTLLoader(appPath) {
        var mtlLoader = new MTLLoader(); 
        return mtlLoader;
    }

    setupObjLoader(materials, appPath) {
        var objLoader = new OBJLoader();
        return objLoader;
    }
}
```

but `angular-cli` complains that:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'OBJLoader' in '/my-path/src/app/shared/services'
 @ ./src/app/shared/services/loader.service.ts 12:0-39
```

Several questions here:

- What do I need to change to get this to work?
- Does the typings folder examine the `@types` folder in the `node_nodules` for declared types?
- How do scripts get loaded in and made available in typescript?

I'm confused as to what to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Joe Clay for the help but I ended up going with an alternative to allow me to `require` whatever file/s I needed. I edited the `typings.d.ts` file at the root of the `src` folder and added this:

```
/* Allow the use of require in the code  */
declare var require : any;
```

This allowed me to use the following when grabbing the `.MTLLoader` or `.OBJLoader`:

```
var MTLLoader = require('three-mtl-loader');
var OBJLoader = require('three-obj-loader');
```

Comment: Hey there, just curious if you'll have any issues when migrating to Angular v5.x.x with this

Answer (score 1):

The `scripts` section of the CLI config file doesn't relate to `import` and `export` - it just adds the scripts as tags in your HTML. If you want to import something from within `node_modules` that isn't the main export, you can do something along the lines of this:

```
// Your typings would need to match!
import * as OBJLoader from "three/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader";
```

However, if you try to do that you'll immedialy run into a much trickier issue: Neither [`OBJLoader`](https://unpkg.com/three@0.85.2/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js) or [`MTLLoader`](https://unpkg.com/three@0.85.2/examples/js/loaders/MTLLoader.js) are JavaScript/TypeScript modules. They don't export anything, instead just attaching stuff to the global `THREE` variable - which, since you're importing `THREE`, doesn't exist!

By adding typings, you're effectively saying "when I compile my code, these modules will exist", but it doesn't change the reality that the actual files don't match up to this.

You could try to [do some Webpack trickery to make things hook in properly](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/), but that would require ejecting your CLI config and using Webpack on its own...

Honestly, I think the best option here is to just copy the code into your project. Directly importing code from a package's examples seems like it could end up being pretty fragile.

Comment: when you say copy the code into your project do you mean doing that through the .angular-cli.json? Or perhaps (and this is the way it was before) placing it into the assets folder under a libs folder and passing it THREE? I was originally using webpack for this but had to migrate to the angular-cli way of doing things

Comment: @Katana24: If you want to `import` it, you don't want to do either of those options. You'll need to add it in your `src` folder and modify the code so that it exports `OBJLoader` instead of trying to add it to the `THREE` variable.

Comment: @Katana24: Oh - or alternatively, someone's [packaged that up as a NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-obj-loader), so you can just do `import * as OBJLoader from "three-obj-loader"`. You'll still need to write your own typings, but it's probably a lot easier :)

Comment: thanks for that link - i prefer to think that that module only just got uploaded in the past 15 minutes haha