# How to load a 3rd third party library with the Angular 5 CLI?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular5

I am attempting to use a 3rd party library in my Angular 5 app by configuring [global scripts](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts).  This question outlines what I am trying to do although I think this might be at Angular 4: 
 [Loading third party library with Angular-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44331099/loading-third-party-library-with-angular-cli)

The library I am trying to use is shpjs, so my scripts property is:

```
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/shpjs/dist/shp.js"
  ],
```

The app builds fine, but my library is not present in my index.html.  According to the docs:

> These will be loaded exactly as if you had added them in a 
>   tag inside index.html

**Is there another step that I am missing?**

***Update: ***
I had other issues which I finally got sorted out.  To sum up, my script configuration was correct but my import statement in my component was not and I was conflating one issue with another.

In my `component.ts`, I added `import * as shp from 'shpjs';`

And then my test function on my component worked just fine:

```
  openAsGeoJson(url: string) {
    url = 'http://calvinmetcalf.github.io/shapefile-js/files/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip';


    shp(url).then(function (data) {
      if (data) {
        console.log('shapefile data received');
        console.log(data.length);
        console.log(data);
      }

    });
  }
```

My Environment:

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.3
Node: 7.10.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.6.3
```

Comment: *"as if you had"* doesn't mean that's how it's actually done. They're included in the bundled JavaScript.

Comment: ok...that makes sense.  and yes, it's in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesnt get added to the `index.html` as is.

`<script src="../node_modules/shpjs/dist/shp.js" />`

It gets added in `scripts.bundle.js`

There will a script tag in `index.html` as below,

`<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.bundle.js"></script>`

The `shp.js` file will be part of `scripts.bundle.js`, Open this file and you can find `shp.js` contents.